# How to name images so that other image names can't be guessed easily?

Tags: image, security

Users will be able to upload images and the name will be changed so it doesn't have the same name as another file. Using a simple convention like calling them 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on will mean other users can simple type in 4.jpg and see someone else's image.

Is there a way or a convention for naming images different while still ensuring guessing an image name is hard?

Comment: Does the user enter a name for the image? If so, you can generate a hash from their name and use that. Otherwise you can generate a name yourself using a "nice" scheme, and store the image with its hashed name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write a PHP script to generate some pseudo random image name each time, like 21412adfs.jpg.

Better yet, take the name of the file being uploaded, and append a 6 digit random number to it or something, say, 19353--toy--car.png, you could even replace the 6 digit number with a number representing the date of the image uploaded.

Naming conventions can be in any form you want really, whatever works best for your setup and archive purposes. Including the date in the image name can be good, as you could easily sort images into different upload folders depending on their dates, etc.

Comment: When taking uploads from external users, unless need to keep the original file name it's far better to get rid of it. Main reasons are that it opens up a possible vector for attack (unless you heavily clean the name of dangerous constructions like "../"), and if you are supporting the world at large you'll get some rather complicated names (especially Japanese) that can be hard to deal with... and then.. you'll also get the people who like to make a point with names written all in capitals with strings like MONKEY_BIG_MAGIC_APPLE_NUTS on the end ;) -- I actually got that one before.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a hashing function to generate a random string that you can use. For example in PHP you could use the following.

`$filename = md5('SOME RANDOM STRING'.rand(0,200000).time());`

MD5 can sometimes generate the same random string which would cause a filename collision, but the likelyhood of this happening is quite small, and if so ... all you have to do is to run the name generation again - a collision twice in a row is extremely unlikely.

Make sure you change 'SOME RANDOM STRING' to something that only you know and use on your site. It's what's known as a "site salt", it means that outsiders will have a much harder job guessing the names of your generated filenames, because they wont be able to predict and reverse engineer everything that you've put in to the mix to generate it.

Hope that helps?